# Make partition in hard drive in which ubuntu is installed

Tags: partitioning

How to create partition in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using terminal command and make change to partition filesystem to install Windows?

Comment: see http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/ and make the type of partition as NTFS

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is better to run the commands from a live USB/CD of Ubuntu. You need to unmount partitions if you are working from a live system.

If you `sda` is the drive you wish to partition, type:

> `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

You will enter the `fdisk` program. If you type `m` you'll get help on commands that you can use

[image]

Enter `p` to list the current partition table

[image]

Enter `n` to create a new partition. You'll be asked whether to create a logical or primary partition. Hit `l` for logical or `p` for primary. Note that a disk can only have four primary partitions (if using MBR). Next, enter the partition number you want to assign to this new partition.

Next, specify the sector of the disk you want the partition to start at. Press Enter to accept the default sector, which is the first free sector on the disk. Then select the last sector of the partition you want. eg: if you type `+100G`, it will create a new 100GB partition.

[image]

Hit `t` and then `7` to create a `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT` partition (you can type `l` to list out all hex codes corresponding to different partition types)

[image]

Enter `w` to write the changes and exit.

Now you you need to format new partitions with a file system before you can use them. So,

> `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdaX`

Replace `X` with the partition number you entered while creating partition.

To mount it (to a mount point, say, `/mnt/ntfs`) you can use:

> `mount -t ntfs /dev/sdaX /mnt/ntfs`